# how to get common output in array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have array of hashes and i want to check a common field which is present in all hashes

```
@a = current_user.ser.collect{|x| x.team == "sect"}

[true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true]
```

i used collect method and boolean operator so in output its giving array now i wanna a single output like if there is 1 false value in whole array so it should return false only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
res = true
current_user.ser.each{|x| res = res & (x.team == "sect")}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
current_user.ser.all?{|x| x.team == "sect"}
```

And `x.team` doesn't look like hash notation. Are you sure you've provided correct code/description?